# WP Advanced Custom Fields: link images to media file

Tags: wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

In my page templates I'm including an image using the image field, like this:

```
<?php
    $image = get_field('img');
    echo '<img src="' . $image['sizes']['large'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';
?>
```

I'd like to automatically wrap those images with a link to the full-size media file, just like when inserting images using the default WP WYSIWYG editor and selecting "Link To: Media File".

So the html output would be something like:

```
<a href="../link-to-media-file.jpg">
    <img src="../media-file.jpg" alt="alt-text" >
</a>
```

This is probably really simple, and maybe I'm overlooking the obvious, but somehow I'm not coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) try

```
<?php 
$image = get_field( 'image' );
if( ! empty( $image ) ) { 
    // vars
    $url    = $image['url'];
    $title  = $image['title'];
    $alt    = $image['alt'];

    $size   = 'large'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $pic    = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
    $width  = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
    $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That's it! Not sure why I didn't notice it in the acf documentation before posting, but thanks for helping me out.  Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to Volker's answer, try this:

```
<?php $img = get_field('image'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['$size']; // either large, small, medium or a custom size of your own choice! :) ?>" />
```

It's a little tidier and easier to read through, and it outputs the exact same thing.

Check the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) for more info.